# Facebook Notification API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone implemented facebook Notification API in iOS??

I have used it in android its working but for iOS its giving `OAuthException`.
Its in Beta could be a bug in Notification API??

I am using facebook SDK for iOS v 3.18.

## Code

```
NSString *notification_Id =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/notifications", friend];
NSString *app_token = @"APP_ID|APP_SECRET";


NSDictionary *dict_notification =  @{@"href": url,
                                     @"template": @"You have been invited to Choozr Poll by",
                                     @"access_token" : app_token};

                         /* make the API call */

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:notification_Id
                     parameters:dict_notification
                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                     completionHandler:^(
                                         FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         id result,
                                         NSError *error
                                         ) {
                                         /* handle the result */
                                         if (error) {
                                             NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                         }
                                              NSLog(@"%@",result);
  }];
```

## Response from facebook

```
{ > error = { > code = 15; > message = "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."; > type = OAuthException; > }
```

Comment: you should never use the notifications api on the client, only on a server. that is the only place where you should deal with the app secret. notifications are "app-to-user" notifications btw, and should no be used for inviting people.

Comment: I will implement it on server side

Comment: btw, you do know that you cannot send notifications to users who are not authorized in your app, right? ... for obvious reasons (spam and stuff).

Comment: yes i know. Actually i have sent notification using android facebook sdk but for some resaon it wasnt working for ios facebook sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the Facebook notification API on your server side code, not the client.